# Radix Sort Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, linux, radix-sort

So I've got a program here that is intended to examine the runtimes of radix sort. When testing on my Windows machine, everything works perfectly, but when I bring it over to the school's Linux machines (where it is required to run), I get a mysterious segmentation fault. The radix sort algorithm is adapted to handle vectors from the one found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Example_in_C.2B.2B

I'm assuming that my issue comes from the way I'm handling vectors, as I'm still new to them. I tried running it through GDB and I'm not sure what I'm looking at here.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804983e in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator[] (
    this=0xfffeebd0, __n=18) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:696
696           { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0804983e in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator[] (
    this=0xfffeebd0, __n=18) at /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:696
#1  0x08049202 in radix (nums=..., length=135041, largest=0)
    at RadixSort2.cpp:98
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I've included a couple of test print statements inside of the radix function. Every time, the "TEST ME 1" line prints, but the "test me 2" line is less consistent. Sometimes it won't print at all and other times it will print a few times. I think the most I've seen it print is eight times. This makes me even more confused since the only thing that happens between the first test statement and the second is the start of a for loop, but nothing should be executing yet, so why are there some instances where it doesn't run at all? The radix function will be posted below, and the full code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/Shoggoth269/7f6645d01eaf5ba91617

```
void radix(vector<int> & nums, int length, int largest)
{
    list<int> bucket[10];
    int i;

    for(int n = 1; largest >= n; n *= 10)
    {
        cout << endl << "TEST ME 1" << endl;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            cout << endl << "test me 2";
            bucket[(nums[i]/n)%10].push_back(nums[i]);
        }

    for (int k = i = 0; i < 10; bucket[i++].clear())
        for(list<int>::iterator j = bucket[i].begin(); j!=bucket[i].end(); nums[k++] = *    (j++));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably accessing elements that are outside the vector `nums`, i.e. the index `i >= nums.size()`, so you get undefined behaviour. Post a minimal compilable example. Use `.at` instead `[]` operator, the later will spit an exception if you overflow.

Comment: Note: Compiler flags are g++ -o RadixSort -std=c++0x RadixSort2.cpp

Comment: @vsoftco - Why would this not be an issue when I run it on the windows machine? When I call the function, I pass in numbers.size() as the length paramater, so shouldn't i always be within bounds?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow. Like I said, I'm still new to vectors and such. I tried replacing one of the instances with bucket.at(i++) and I'm getting this error: request for member 'at' in 'bucket', which is of non-class type 'std::list<int> [10]'

Comment: sorry, not for the list... only for vector.

Comment: @vsoftco - I do that in Windows and it works, but not in Linux. Just get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. It seems that the error lies in some way that I'm accessing the vector. I tested my print function on Linux now and it crashes on that.

Comment: did you try replacing `nums[...]` with `nums.at(...)` everywhere?

Comment: Note that if nums[i] is negative, then (nums[i]/n%10) will be zero or negative. If a negative value is used as an index into bucket[10], then you get a segmentation fault. If nums[] was an array of unsigned integers, or if the code checked of a negative index and added 10 to it, this potential problem would go away.

Comment: @rcgldr - I think you're touching on the problem here. I'm just confused as to where I'm getting negative numbers from. When I run in Windows and print out the numbers, I get all positive numbers, but when I run in Linux, I get some negative numbers. Why is rand() giving me negative numbers? I even made a simple test program just for random number generation and that's happening for it as well.

Comment: Problem solved. RAND_MAX on this Linux machine is 2147483647, where it's only 32767 on my Windows machine. I didn't want a lot of duplicates on the N = 100000 test, so I multiplied the value from rand() by 4, giving it a max of 131068. In hindsight, this wasn't the best way to do it, as it would still have only 32767 values, they'd just all be four times greater than without that multiplication. I should have just added together a couple calls of rand(). Anyways, when I did this on the Linux machine, it was causing massive overflow, hence my negative numbers. Algorithms run fine now.